# Google gmail list API returns id and threadId only, As per documentation i am not getting payload in message

Tags: node.js, gmail-api

I am calling gmail.users.messages.list in node js. in response it retruns id and threadId for message.
but as per gmail document (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list) it is not returning payload in message.

see below:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code and not images of your code preferably a [example]

Answer (score 1):

- To see the payload you need to use the method [users.messages.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get) for each of the messages you retrieved with [users.messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list).
- Alternatively, you can also perform a [batch request](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch) to get all messages at one  - see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636938/gmail-api-batch-get-support).